# Not able to access Jolokia endpoint from Openshift

Tags: openshift, spring-boot-actuator, hawtio, jolokia

I have deployed an hawtio enabled spring-boot application in an openshift environment. But I am facing issue in accessing Jolokia endpoint through hawtio.

I noticed On the pod logs of my application, that set of actuator endpoints are exposed during startup where the Jolokia endpoint is not listed in that.

But I also could observe the below information in the startup logs
Jolokia: Agent started with URL https://ipaddress:8778/jolokia/

Bascially I suspect a conflict between the Jolokia endpoint that comes with spring-actuator and Openshift default Jolokia capabilities causing this issue.

Any Idea or Suggestion about the issue and fix?

Answer (score 2):

*This issue is resolved now*

*Solution: Disable the default Jolokia in openshift.*

This issue has been resolved by disabling the default Jolokia through environment variable in openshift as per the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_middleware_for_openshift/3/html-single/red_hat_java_s2i_for_openshift/index#version_details) . Added the below Env variable:

AB_JOLOKIA_OFF: true